# CUDA_ERROR_INVALID_DEVICE using gpuDevice() in MATLAB

Tags: linux, matlab, cuda, mex

When I run `gpuDevice()` from Parallel Computing Toolbox in MATLAB on an 64bit archlinux with dual GPU (one intel, one Nvidia GT 650M, with nvidia driver installed and bumblebee).

I get the following error:

```
Error using gpuDevice (line 26)
An unexpected error occurred during CUDA execution. The CUDA error was:
CUDA_ERROR_INVALID_DEVICE
```

I didn' t get any google result about the error. What could be the reason?

And I'm trying to get a mex with CUDA working, and it crashes with:

```
[NVBLAS] Cannot open default config file 'nvblas.conf'
Segmentation fault
```

I feel the two thing might be related.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [matlab documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/distcomp/gpudevice.html):

> D = gpuDevice or D = gpuDevice(), if no device is already selected, selects the default GPU device and returns an object representing that device. If a GPU device is already selected, this returns an object representing that device without clearing it.

From [CUDA documentation](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/4_1/rel/toolkit/docs/online/group__CUDA__TYPES_g0cdead942fd5028d157641eef6bdeeaa.html):

> CUDA_ERROR_INVALID_DEVICE -    This indicates that the device ordinal supplied by the user does not correspond to a valid CUDA device.

Therefore my guess would be you are selecting wrong GPU by call to that function. Try to either investigate return value of that call to see which GPU is selected or simply replace the call by gpuDevice(1) or gpuDevice(2) and see which one will work.

For the second question, it was already asked and also answered on [NVIDIA forum](https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/720115/having-trouble-with-nvblas/):

> You need to set the environment variable “NVBLAS_CONFIG_FILE” to point to the nvblas.conf file. Instructions on how to create the conf file are in page 9 of the NVBLAS documentation that comes with the CUDA 6 RC toolkit

Sorry for not commenting under your question firt, requesting more info, but I do not have enough reputation to post comments yet.

Comment: Well, after reboot , the gpuDevice() returns fine. And thanks for the pointing to the documentation on NVBLAS. Now that error is gone and I only get a clueless `Segmentation fault`.